# How use react-rails with webpacker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, react-rails, webpacker

I created example project react-rails with webpacker. but show error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Person is not defined". help me How use react-rails with webpacker?
The processing I performed is as follows.

Rails version

```
$ rails -v
Rails 5.0.2
```

Gem version

```
react-rails (2.1.0)
webpacker (1.1)
```

Create Rails project

```
$ rails new example
```

Add webpacker and react-rails to Gemfile

```
gem 'webpacker', github: 'rails/webpacker'
gem "react-rails"
```

Install webpacker and react

```
$ rails webpacker:install
$ rails webpacker:install:react
$ rails generate react:install
```

Create controller

```
$ bin/rails g controller home
```

Add route

```
config/routes.rb
root "home#index"
```

Add react component

```
$ bin/rails g react:component person name --es6
```

Add react_component tag

```
app/views/home/index.html.erb
<%= react_component("Person", { name: "Hello" }) %>
```

Add javascript_pack_tag to application.html.erb

```
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

Run server

```
$ bin/rails s
$ bin/webpack-dev-server
```

Show error console

```
VM27375:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Person is not defined
    at eval (eval at module.exports (fromGlobal.js?fc31:13), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at module.exports (fromGlobal.js?fc31:13)
    at Object.getConstructor (fromRequireContextWithGlobalFallback.js?cbbb:16)
    at Object.mountComponents (index.js?c0e8:82)
    at HTMLDocument.ReactRailsUJS.handleMount (index.js?c0e8:124)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:5227)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery.self-bd7ddd3….js?body=1:4879)
```

example project

https://github.com/yokochi/webpacker_example

Comment: have you solved your problem? I'm also wasting my time :) to solve how it should work... :(

Comment: @Rafath see my answer.

Comment: Did you compare react-rails to https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails?

Answer (score 2):

Either rename `app/javascript/components/person.js` to `app/javascript/components/Person.js` (e.g. capitalize)

Or use `react_component('person')` instead.

TLDR; capitalization matters.

Comment: I've renamed file, how ever new issue came...

`[react-rails] Cannot find component: 'Post' for element <div data-react-class="Post" data-react-props="{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Hello World&quot;}">  application.js:29060:11
Error: Cannot find component: 'Post'. Make sure your component is available to render.`

I've tried to include javascript above or below the component - without any luck ;(

Comment: @Rafath just to confirm: your file is named `app/javascript/components/Post.js` and you've installed webpacker using the steps here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails#use-with-webpacker, yes?

Comment: ofcourse this issue is solved - renaming file solved the problem with Uncaught ReferenceError, but after this I've got issue with 'cannot find component' :(

Comment: @Rafath Can you push a sample repository so I can help you better?

Answer (score 2):

@Akio Yamazaki

https://github.com/yokochi/webpacker_example/commit/55ca96c1257e611dfb17b27fe53b402a97d5dedc#diff-0c7c7cb70dec34ec9dcff19a0f5bd40bR1

you should require('react') in your component and export component

try this...

```
var React = require("react")

class Person extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Name: {this.props.name}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Person.propTypes = {
  name: React.PropTypes.node
};

module.exports = Person
```

but this way be better

```
import React from 'react'

class Person extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    <div>Name: {this.props.name}</div>
  }
}

export default Person
```

or...

```
import React from 'react'

const Person = props => (
  <div>Name: {props.name}</div>
)

export default Person
```

I have a repo maybe able to give some reference

https://github.com/kakas/react-rails_with_webpacker_example/commits/master

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late, I had the same problem and I solved changing version in my Gemfile; this should work:

```
gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.7', '>= 1.7.1'
```